# How do I find the item clicked in this recycler adapter. I want to use this code itself

Tags: android, adapter, android-recyclerview

Please help me to add a code which can provide me the name of item clicked.
You see I cant find the apt solution. I want to keep the current code due to certain reasons. I just need some extra code that can help me find out the item that is clicked.

public class itemsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
private Context context;
private List<items> list;

public itemsAdapter(Context context, List<items> list) {
    this.context = context;
    this.list = list;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.single_item, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    items item1 = list.get(position);

    holder.textTitle.setText(item1.getTitle());


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView textTitle;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        textTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.main_title);

    }

}
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RecyclerView onClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471109/recyclerview-onclick)

Answer (score 1):

This way you can perform onClick Listener in RecyclerView.

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               onClickSubject.onNext(element);
            }
        });
```